# Converting all pandas column: row to key:value pair json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a new column at the end of my pandas dataframe that will contain the values of previous cells in key:value pair. I have tried the following:

```
import json

df["json_formatted"] = df.apply
            (
                lambda row: json.dumps(row.to_dict(), ensure_ascii=False), axis=1
            )
```

It creates the the column `json_formatted` successfully with all required data, but the problem is it also adds the `json_formatted` as another extra key. I don't want that. I want the json data to contain only the information from the original df columns. How can I do that?

Note: I made `ensure_ascii=False` because the column names are in Japanese characters.

Comment: please follow the guideline here in providing a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable holding the created column and add it afterwards:

```py
json_formatted = df.apply(lambda row: json.dumps(row.to_dict(), ensure_ascii=False), axis=1)
df['json_formatted'] = json_formatted
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This behaviour shouldn't happen, but might be caused by your having run this function more than once. (You added the column, and then ran `df.apply` on the same dataframe).
2. You can avoid this by making your columns explicit: `df[['col1', 'col2']].apply()`
3. Apply is an expensive operation is Pandas, and if performance matters it is better to avoid it. An alternative way to do this is

   ```
   df["json_formatted"] = [json.dumps(s, ensure_ascii=False) for s in df.T.to_dict().values()]
   ```